# Can the category of sets become a daggery category?

Tags: category-theory, hilbert-spaces

I came across the claim that the category of finite dimensional Hilbert spaces, FHilb, where objects are Hilbert spaces and morphisms are bounded linear operators is a dagger category, i.e. it has a contravariant involutive functor. Then, it was suggested that this is a good reason of why we should use the framework of category theory because the category of sets, Set, does not have a dagger structure so it's better to think of Hilbert spaces from a categorical perspective rather than a set-theoretic one.
Can someone explain why we cannot turn Set into a dagger structure?

Comment: This seems like a very dubious reason to think of Hilbert spaces from a categorical perspective rather than a set-theoretic one.

Comment: How would you define a functor on the function $\emptyset \to \{*\}?$

Comment: @EricWofsey the context here was the mathematical structure of quantum mechanics and its relations to the category of n-dimensional cobordisms.

Comment: The category of sets and maps doesn't support a dagger structure, but the category of sets and relations does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $\dagger$ is a dagger structure on $\mathsf{Set}$. Let $X$ be any non-empty set, and let $f\colon \emptyset\to X$ be the empty function. Then $f^\dagger$ is a function $X\to \emptyset$. This is a contradiction, since are no functions from a non-empty set to the empty set.